# Disable empty SectionGroup (NSIS)

Tags: nsis

In my script I have the conditional header inside a SectionGroup where sections are created at compile time.
If sections are not created SectionGroup exists and not checkable. How can I disable it if sections are not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the name to empty to hide a section and/or group.

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Components
Page InstFiles

Function HideEmptyGroup
Exch $3
Push $0
Push $1
Push $2
StrCpy $0 $3
StrCpy $2 ""
ClearErrors
loop:
SectionGetFlags $0 $1
IfErrors done
${If} $1 & ${SF_SECGRPEND}
    ${If} $2 = 1
        SectionSetText $3 ""
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $2 $2 - 1
${ElseIf} $1 & ${SF_SECGRP}
    IntOp $2 $2 + 1
${Else}
    Goto done
${EndIf}
IntOp $0 $0 + 1
Goto loop
done:
Pop $2
Pop $1
Pop $0
Pop $3
FunctionEnd

SectionGroup /e "My Group" SID_MYGROUP

!if 0 ; Set to 1 to show section and group
Section "Thing"
SectionEnd
!endif

SectionGroupEnd

Function .onInit ; Note: This must come after the sections!
Push ${SID_MYGROUP}
Call HideEmptyGroup
FunctionEnd
```